# How can I order this MySQL Date?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem ordering a mysql result by Date. The date is in this format: 15:24:57 - 21/04/2019 (24 hour clock)

I've tried this:

```
SELECT PlayerSteamID, BanLength, BanReason, AdminName, AdminSteamID, PlayerName, MapName, DateAndHour FROM BansList ORDER BY DateAndHour DESC
```

and this

```
SELECT PlayerSteamID, BanLength, BanReason, AdminName, AdminSteamID, PlayerName, MapName, DateAndHour FROM BansList ORDER BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(DateAndHour, '%h:%i:%s - %d/%m/%Y')) DESC
```

But doesn't seem to work...

How can I make it so it's ordered by that date & time?

Comment: try with `ORDER BY DATE(DateAndHour) DESC` mysql engine auto adapt the format.if is the `datatype` is `DATE

Comment: which data type is the DateAndHour ???

Comment: What type is the `DateAndHour` column? If it is a `datetime` or `timestamp`, then `ORDER BY DateAndHour` should work fine by itself. (And if it's not one of those types, why not?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming your DateAndHour column is a string  could be you need  a proper conversion

```
  SELECT PlayerSteamID
    , BanLength
    , BanReason
    , AdminName
    , AdminSteamID
    , PlayerName
    , MapName
    , DateAndHour 
  FROM BansList
  ORDER BY str_to_date(DateAndHour, '%T - %d/%m/%Y')  DESC
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think of that! I'll mark your answer in 7 minutes :)

Comment: I did, i had to wait because if their system